How to project textures on to the mesh and overlap them like in Let’s Play Pottery?

I want to learn how to project textures on to the mesh and overlap them like in Let’s Play Pottery. I have an idea for game. I created Models, 3d viewer but I can’t figure out how to implement texture part. Can anybody tell me how they implemented it.

Are your models basically distorted cylinders like this example? Do they have UV texture coordinates created?

I tired both. I took a unity cylinder and then made a cylinder with UV in Maya. With some help from ChatGPT I wrote a shader that could project a material in a horizontal stripe but only once and UV didn't matter in this approach, then someone told me that I should use graph shader for this and not code. I have never used graph shader before and that confused me more. So, I am just confused how did they implemented this. what approach and logic should I search for.

To layer multiple stripes, you'll probably want to stamp them into a RenderTexture. Then your shader can be very simple - it doesn't need to know the texture was made through stamping, it just displays it like any other texture.
